# What is this Python syntax? [X_train_A, X_train_B = X_train[:, :5], X_train[:, 2:]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm currently reading through "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow" and came across this Python code:

```
X_train_A, X_train_B = X_train[:, :5], X_train[:, 2:]
```

What does the notation [:, :5] and [:, 2:] represent? I know that it's slice notation, but can't find what this specific operation is doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: It's splitting `X_train` by column.  The first 5 columns go to `X_train_A`, All but the first 2 to `B`.

Comment: Got it, thank you!